# Python: My function returns "None" after it does what I want it to

Tags: python

Here is my program

```
def reverse(letters):
    backwards = ""
    i = len(letters) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        backwards = backwards + letters[i]
        i = i - 1
    print (backwards)

print (reverse("hello"))
```

It works, it prints out "olleh" but after, it prints "None" on a new line. And I'm asking why this is.
Obviously the program is to reverse a word, the code works, and without a function it doesn't print none, so I don't know why it does in the function. This is being used in another larger program, so I need it as a function, and because it's for school, I'm not allowed to simply use the .reverse() function. So I really need this code fixed rather than large changes, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

function return `None` by default, so you should  `return backwards` explicitly

also, you can use a pythonic way to solve the problem:

```
letters[::-1]
```

Comment: upvoting for pythonic way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a return statement to exit the function returning a value. If the function gets to the end without reaching a return statement, it will return None by default

```
def add1(x):
   return x+1

def returnsNone():
   pass

print(add1(2))
print(returnsNone())
```

Comment: What language is this? Neither of these definitions are valid python syntax.

Comment: @Max: come on, the first one was just missing a colon :)

Comment: @missingno: Not just that.  `end` doesn't mean anything special in Python.

Comment: @DSM: O shit. I guess I spent too much time with Lua lately.

Comment: [Removed downvote now that defs are fixed]

Answer (score 1):

Every function returns *something* in Python. If you don't explicitly return a value, Python has your function return `None`.

Your function doesn't actually return anything because `print` prints to stdout, while `return` actually returns a value. They may *look* the same in the REPL, but they're completely different.

So to fix your problem, return a value:

```
return backwards
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just:

```
 reverse(hello)
```

In fact with

```
print reverse(hello)
```

you are printing the return value of reverse. And that return value is None.

Let me give you few general advises:

reverse() in your code is a function with side effects (printing). You should avoid 
functions with side effects when you don't need, consider having reverse() returning the word instead of printing it:

```
def reverse(letters):
    backwards = ""
    i = len(letters) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        backwards = backwards + letters[i]
        i = i - 1
    return backwards
print (reverse("hello"))
```

Moreover

```
i = len(letters) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        backwards = backwards + letters[i]
        i = i - 1
```

is not easy to mantain and if you add functionality to the loop the decrement i=i-1 will be far from the place where it should 'conceptually' be. You should prefer having decrement together with the check:

```
for i in xrange(len(letters)-1,-1,-1): 
    backwards = backwards + letters[i]
```

When I'm lazy I write

```
myString = myString + fewChars
```

so I can understand you being lazy. But adding fewChars does not modify myString but creates a new one. If you are iteratively adding many chars, rarely the most efficient way is to add one by one. Consider using join(). 
For instance

```
letters = 'word'
lettersList = [letters[i] for i in xrange(len(letters)-1,-1,-1)]
myReversed ''.join(lettersList)
```

ok I agree is not readable and probably not even faster, but for larger strings it scales better than a newString = oldString + oneChar approach.

That said, more pythonic approaches

```
letters[::-1]
```

already suggested by someone faster than me typically works much better and are easy to be read by python programmers.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense if you think about it. Your `reverse` does not return anything - it just prints it's result. But when you write `print (reverse("hello"))`, you are actually printing what `reverse` returns. Since it doesn't return anything, `None` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier. If the python function does not come across a `return` statement it prints `None` by default. Making a small change as shown below fixes this:

```
def reverse(letters):
    backwards = ""
    i = len(letters) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        backwards = backwards + letters[i]
    i = i - 1
    return(backwards)  # instead of print(backwards)

print(reverse("hello"))
```

Comment: s/prints/returns/