# Why do I keep getting the output I want and an unwanted "none"

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def car(wheels,bodies,figures):
  car_by_wheels=wheels//4
  car_by_figures=figures/2
  if figures//2 >= car_by_wheels and bodies >= car_by_wheels:
    print(car_by_wheels)
  elif car_by_wheels >= car_by_figures and bodies >= car_by_figures:
    print(car_by_figures)
  elif car_by_wheels >= bodies and car_by_figures >= bodies:
    print(bodies)
  else:
    print("0")

print(car(3,29,54))
```

I tried a few other examples and the code works fine but I keep getting `None`. Why?

Comment: I noticed a coding error....probably caused when I tried to change "/" to "//"...more of a typo really. Anyway, I fixed that and I still have the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the formal difference between "print" and "return"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: My function returns "None" after it does what I want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105961/python-my-function-returns-none-after-it-does-what-i-want-it-to)

Comment: you need to `return` the value if you want to print outside the function, or you should simply run your function `car(3,29,54)` in last line instead of print().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't explicitly return anything, so it implicitly returns `None`. So `car(3,29,54)` does it's printing and returns `None`, which you then print.